# Algorithm - Longest Common Subsequence Memoization

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a famous problem of longest common subsequence - given 2 strings, return the longest subsequence. To specify, my goal is to return the actual sequence, not the length of the sequence. For example, inputs "ABCD", "BD" would output "BD". Below is the code I wrote, and I'm not sure what is wrong with the "memo" hash table I'm using. Guessing the key is not specific enough but not sure why. How could I solve this problem using recursion and a memo array/ hash table? I know it is solvable with a bottom-up dynamic programming algorithm, but would like to practice more with top-down approach. Thank you!

```
def longestCommonSubsequence(str1, str2):
    memo = {}
    def recurse(i, j, sub):
        key = (i, j)
        
        if i == len(str1) or j == len(str2):
            return sub
        if str1[i] == str2[j]:
            res = recurse(i + 1, j + 1, sub + [str1[i]])
            memo[key] = res
            return res
        if key in memo:
            return memo[key]
        
        first = recurse(i + 1, j, sub)
        second = recurse(i, j + 1, sub)
        
        res = first if len(first) > len(second) else second
        memo[key] = res
        return res
    
    return recurse(0, 0, [])
```

Comment: The inputs you gave, 'ABCD' and 'BD', do return ['B', 'D']. Is the problem that it's a list instead of a string?

Comment: When in doubt, add some `print` statements. For memoization algorithms, what you want to see is the updates to the `memo` table.  Putting a `print 'memo[{}] = {}'.format(key, res)` after each `memo[key] = res` makes the problem pretty obvious.

Comment: btw, reversing the strings (`longestCommonSubsequence('BD', 'ABCD')` instead of `longestCommonSubsequence('ABCD', 'BD')`) gives you a simple test case that *doesn't* work.